# Changing a Combobox selected Item

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Here's what I need to do:
I have a ComboBox that has a whole list of items, for this example lets just call them `1, 2, 3`.
If someone selects `3` I want to reset the ComboBox.
So if I was to select `3`, the ComboBox would then return to its default blank state.

I just want to make this clear that I don't want the actual ComboBox to *reset*, that is, I don't want to remove the items I have listed in it. I just want the selection to go blank again.

Comment: `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LarsTech said, set the SelectedIndex = -1. Here is a complete example with just a ComboBox on the form.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    If CInt(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue) = 3 Then
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks so much djv, LarsTech! I never thought to think of SelectedIndex, before I was doing things such as SelectedItem, and stuff like that! Thanks for the quick replies!